# Issue in building Tensorboard 1.13.1 from source (cfg must be either 'host' or 'target')

Tags: tensorboard

I am trying to build Tensorboard (1.13.1) from source. I am using Bazel version 0.26.0 (built from source) and JDK version 11.0.3. I am getting following error during build:

```
# bazel build --incompatible_disallow_filetype=false --incompatible_bzl_disallow_load_after_statement=false  tensorboard
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/compiler/closure_js_library.bzl:343:17: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/compiler/closure_js_library.bzl", line 335
                rule(implementation = _closure_js_lib..., <2 more arguments>)
        File "/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/compiler/closure_js_library.bzl", line 343, in rule
                attr.label_list(cfg = "data", allow_files = True)
cfg must be either 'host' or 'target'.
ERROR: error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/defs.bzl: Extension file 'closure/compiler/closure_js_library.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/io_bazel_rules_closure/closure/defs.bzl: Extension file 'closure/compiler/closure_js_library.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 14.290s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

If I search and replace the word 'data' with 'host' from .bzl files, I start getting another error:

```
# bazel build --incompatible_disallow_filetype=false --incompatible_bzl_disallow_load_after_statement=false  tensorboard
ERROR: error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl: Label '@org_tensorflow//third_party:nccl/nccl_configure.bzl' crosses boundary of subpackage '@org_tensorflow//third_party/nccl' (perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@org_tensorflow//third_party/nccl:nccl_configure.bzl'?)
ERROR: error loading package '': in /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl: Label '@org_tensorflow//third_party:nccl/nccl_configure.bzl' crosses boundary of subpackage '@org_tensorflow//third_party/nccl' (perhaps you meant to put the colon here: '@org_tensorflow//third_party/nccl:nccl_configure.bzl'?)
INFO: Elapsed time: 15.377s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Correcting the error by replacing,

```
load("//third_party:nccl/nccl_configure.bzl", "nccl_configure")
```

by

```
load("//third_party/nccl:nccl_configure.bzl", "nccl_configure")
```

in the cache file,

```
/root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl
```

Solves the error but now getting this error:

```
# bazel build --incompatible_disallow_filetype=false --incompatible_bzl_disallow_load_after_statement=false  tensorboard
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/4e113d18791d4c114d32fe59cdd54b1a/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/workspace.bzl:18:1: file '@io_bazel_rules_closure//closure:defs.bzl' does not contain symbol 'filegroup_external'
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file 'tensorflow/workspace.bzl' has errors
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file 'tensorflow/workspace.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.113s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Now I am stuck. Any pointers highly appreciated!